# Angular 5 - Auth0Lock makes up reload after login

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

I've just started to use Auth0 in my Angular application. And there is a problem. When I register a new user (e.g. via sign up with google), I get redirected to the google account selection page. And then get redirected back to my application.

The problem here is that it makes app to reload which results in a bad user experience. Since this is a SPA, page reloading is highly undesirable.

Is it possible, for example, to open that auth provider page (like google account selection) in a new window? Or any other option that wouldn't make the app to reload?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution just now. Somehow I didn't notice it at first.

You can simply set auth0lock options to:

`var options = {
  auth: {
    redirect: false
  }
};`